# How to run if-else in jexl?

Tags: jexl

Here are 3 INT parameters:a,b,c. And 1 String parameter:d.
Here is code in Java:

```
if (a>1) return c+d;
if (b<2) return c-d;
if (d.equals("123") return c*d;
return c+1;
```

How to turn above code to Jexl?
I tried many times, including using var. But it always return null.

Answer (score 5):

Probably you use JEXL expression instead of script.
You can use only Ternary conditional in expression.
if-else, return, for, while should be used in script:

```
JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().create();
JexlScript script = jexl.createScript(scriptText);
result = script.execute(context);
```

See http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jexl/reference/syntax.html

From javadoc:

> An expression is different than a script - it is simply a reference to a single expression, not to multiple statements.
>   This implies 'if','for','while','var' and blocks '{'... '}'are NOT allowed in expressions.
>
> A script is some valid JEXL syntax to be executed with a given set of JexlContext variables.
>   A script is a group of statements, separated by semicolons.
>   The statements can be blocks (curly braces containing code), Control statements such as if and while as well as expressions and assignment statements.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem when I wanted to display an int as a string in DBeaver. I want to keep the database size small, so I store enums as ints. However, I wanted to see the textual value directly in the database. That's why I used this expression to create a virtual column.

```
MyEnum == 1 ? 'A' : MyEnum == 2 ? 'B' : MyEnum == 3 ? 'C' : 'Undefined'
```